# Flash pull in images from directory

Tags: image, flash, slider

I'm trying to create a flash image slider however I need the images to be pulled into the flash file from a directory and then to transition fade through to the next ones.

Has anyone got any ideas of where to start on this or any links that could help?

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull in images from a local or server directory? For a server directory you would use the Flash Loader class [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html)

If you are using Adobe AIR then you can load local files using FileReference.

For fading, I use [Tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) and tween the alpha value of the from image and the to image to make one fade out and the other fade in.

Answer (score 1):

Flash can't read the content of the folder.

You either have to specify the file name(s) manualy either use a server-side script to create a list of the files in the folder - it may be passed to Flash as a XML, text file or just a query string, up to you.